# How to pass images url through props in vue.js (with URL links)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

So, I have this component

```
<template>
  <div class="newsitem">
    <img src="${{imageurl}}" alt="newsimage" width="200" height="100">
    <h1 class="newstitle">{{title}}</h1>
    <p class="newsdescription">{{description}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  props: {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    imageurl: String
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

The `imageurl` is an actual online link to an image. But I cannot see an image on my page.

Does someone know, how to pass it right to the image src?

This is where the prop comes from:

```
<NewsItem :title="nachricht.title" :description="nachricht.description" :imageurl="nachricht.urlToImage"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just bind the image src, like `<img :src="imageurl" alt="newsimage" width="200" height="100">`:

```js
Vue.component('NewsItem', {
  template: `
    <div class="newsitem">
      <img :src="imageurl" alt="newsimage" width="200" height="100">
      <h1 class="newstitle">{{title}}</h1>
      <p class="newsdescription">{{description}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    imageurl: String
  },
})
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      nachricht: {title: 'aaa', description: 'aaaaaa', urlToImage: 'https://picsum.photos/200'}
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <news-item :title="nachricht.title" :description="nachricht.description" :imageurl="nachricht.urlToImage"></news-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! So easy and I didn't get it.